# multiple if else condition in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, database

I'm not good in javascript so i was jud experimenting  a code. I want to have a multiple condition with different equalization that will subtract a value. this is my sample code but it didn't function, only the first condition functioned.

```
  var input = document.getElementById("amount");

var first = 30;
var second = 50;
var third = 60;

input.addEventListener("keyup", function () {

    if (input = first) {
       document.getElementById('rebate').value = document.getElementById('amount').value - 2;
     }
    else if (input = second) {
      document.getElementById('rebate').value = document.getElementById('amount').value - 2.50;
     }
    else if (input = third) {
      document.getElementById('rebate').value = document.getElementById('amount').value - 3;
     }
});

function sum() {
        var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
        var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('amount').value;
        var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) + parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
        if (!isNaN(result)) {
            document.getElementById('total').value = result;
        }
    }
```

**html**

```
 <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="amount">Amount</label>
                        <input type="text" id="txt1"  onkeyup="sum();" value="5" hidden>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control " id="amount" name="amount" placeholder="00" required onkeyup="sum();">
                    </div>

 <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="total">Total</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="total" name="total" placeholder="00" required readonly >
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


<div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="total">With Rebate</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rebate" name="rebate" required readonly >
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

It would be great guys if you could help me. ^^

Comment: You can't use `=` to compare values. You use `=` to assign values.

Comment: ahhh okays..but how should i do that?

Comment: Use == instead of = to compare values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace all of your `=` with `==` inside the if statements.

Also, `var input = document.getElementById("amount")` only grabs a reference to the element, not the value.

So in your if statements you need to write `input.value == first`, etc

Here is a JSFiddle that work: https://jsfiddle.net/bbjpg9np/

- When the the user types 30, "With Rebate 28"
- When the the user types 50, "With Rebate 47.5"
- When the the user types 60, "With Rebate 57"

Comment: Provide your html and we could help you better

Comment: Haha, sorry i got to post the fiddle link. My fiddle solves your rebate problem. I guess the `sum()` is irrelevant now

Comment: I've got it sir...thank you soo muchh...it really helps ^^